# Dash, command substitution not inserting newline?

Tags: command-line, dash-shell

Basically, this is the issue:

```
$ echo Hello"$(printf '\n')"World
HelloWorld
```

What did I overlook ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is actually part of the POSIX [specification for command substitution](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03):

> The shell shall expand the command substitution by executing command
>   in a subshell environment (see Shell Execution Environment) and
>   replacing the command substitution (the text of command plus the
>   enclosing "$()" or backquotes) with the standard output of the
>   command, **removing sequences of one or more  characters at the
>   end of the substitution**. Embedded  characters before the end
>   of the output shall not be removed; however, they may be treated as
>   field delimiters and eliminated during field splitting, depending on
>   the value of IFS and quoting that is in effect. If the output contains
>   any null bytes, the behavior is unspecified.

So the normal quoting rule `"$(...)"` only preserves non-trailing newlines.

Some suggestions for preserving trailing newlines are given in [shell: keep trailing newlines ('\n') in command substitution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383217/shell-keep-trailing-newlines-n-in-command-substitution)

See also [When printing a variable that contains newlines, why is the last newline stripped?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/446992/when-printing-a-variable-that-contains-newlines-why-is-the-last-newline-strippe) for discussion of the rationale behind the specification.